# Cordova how to flip the whole screen front side to back 3D effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, cordova

I saw an app, when you click on a button, it flips the entire screen front side back and it's a 3D effect on iPhone(hopefully my expression makes sense to you).

The guy told me he only uses WebView in Cordova.

Sorry I don't have a screenshot to show you the effect.

So I am grateful if some one can point me to the right direction, which library to use to create this kind of effect.

Thank you.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Are you looking for the app, or trying to get the code to do the effect?

Comment: Jquery mobile does that effect and many more --- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Comment: @sdsanders hi I tried yours, it works in all 3 browers, Chrome, IE10 and Firefox. but where to download your library?

Comment: hi @sdsanders yours seems like the best one now, can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @user3802489 - I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get it working with jQuery Mobile really quick.This is an example: http://goo.gl/3GSUus

Comment: hi jt, thx. I tried your code it works great in Chrome, but in Firefox the transition is too quick to see. Is there any way to specify the time of transition? thanks

Comment: Yes you can: http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/Txj3j/1/, just change the values in css